# Is there a new way to compare element of the same list in java 8 with lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way to compare elements within a list in java 8?

I am interested in re writing the two for loops.

```
private static void test(List<Foo> a) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < a.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < a.size() ; j++){
            Foo o1= a.get(i);
            Foo o2= a.get(j);
            if (o1.getFooA().equals(o2.getFooA()) && !o1.getFooB().equals(o2.getFooB()) ) {
                    throw new Exception("some message goes here...");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Is there a cool way to do this with lambdas/streams or any other feature that came across with java 8?

Comment: Nothing that would make the code more readable than this traditional approach.

Comment: Note that your comparison is unnecessary inefficient as your comparison is symmetric, so comparing `a with b` would yield the same than `b with a` but your nested loop generates both comparisons. So the complexity of this could be drastically decreased. For that, just let the second loop start at `int j = i` instead of `int j = 1`. So if you have pairs like `(1, 1)`, `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)`, `(2, 2)` the pair `(2, 1)` is obsolete as its already covered by `(1, 2)`. Also note that you can skip the case `j == i` as the comparison is then always `false`, so just `int j = i + 1`.

Comment: Do you want to see if two lists are identical, i.e. that both lists contain the same elements?

Comment: Hi @Zabuza ,thank you for your note I will defenetly use your advice! Do you think your solution is deasable using lambda, or any java 8 feature?

Comment: Hi @Abra , no the goal is to know if I can do this type of comparison using lambda

Comment: You can certainly do this with the stream API but the outcome will most likely not be any more readable than this, probably worse. This is not a good fit for the stream API as you have to traverse two collections at the same time.

Comment: @Zabuza - This doesn't alter the complexity.  Your optimization does roughly half the comparisons to the original, but `N*N` and `N*N/2` are both in the `O(N^2)` complexity class.

Comment: A lambda in java is the implementation of a functional interface, i.e. an interface that contains precisely one abstract method. Think of a method that encapsulates the operation you want to perform, wrap it in a functional interface, then write a lambda that implements the interface. Or are you asking if there already is such a functional interface in the JDK?

Comment: He is most likely asking for an approach that uses the Stream API. People often confuse that with "lambdas" as it heavily uses functional interfaces which _can_ be used with lambdas.

Comment: The question is not about performance or complexity, the question is related to the new feature that came across with java 8. I have seen a lot of changes such as lambdas and other features which I am not mentioning here. I wonder if there is a way to compare elements of the same list using java 8 new features.

Comment: @OEH Usually while programming you should take care of both aspects: readablity and performance.

Comment: @Zabuza `Nothing that would make the code more readable than this traditional approach.` . Note that **more readable != right**. Very often the `naive` algorithms are super easy to read (e.g. Bubble Sort), but at the same time they have very bad performance.

Comment: Agreed, but then you would also change the above implementation/approach. Depends on if OP wants this, id guess.

Answer (score 3):

Don’t ask for “lambdas/streams” but actual improvement.

When you use

```
private static void test(List<Foo> a) throws Exception {
    Map<TypeOfFooA, TypeOfFooB> seen = new HashMap<>();
    for(Foo f: a) {
        TypeOfFooB fooB = f.getFooB(), previous = seen.putIfAbsent(f.getFooA(), fooB);
        if(previous != null && !fooB.equals(previous))
            throw new Exception("some message goes here...");
    }
}
```

you are performing the operation in a single pass, instead of nested loops. This makes the difference between linear and quadratic time complexity. Which has more impact than “looking cool”.

You could rewrite this to use the Stream API like

```
private static void test(List<Foo> a) throws Exception {
    Map<TypeOfFooA, TypeOfFooB> seen = a.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getFooA, Foo::getFooB,
            (previous, fooB) -> {
                if(!fooB.equals(previous))
                    throw new RuntimeException("some message goes here...");
                return previous;
            }));
}
```

But it’s not recommended. Collecting to a map which is not really needed afterwards, combined with using the merge/reduction function to do validation and throwing an exception, may be surprising to readers and it only works for unchecked exceptions. Further, the throwing function can’t access neither, the `Foo` instance nor `FooA` key, for constructing the exception message.

I recommend staying with the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is an optimized, but not so obvious solution:

```
a.stream()
 .collect(toMap(Foo::getFooA, Foo::getFooB, (x, y) -> {
     if (x.equals(y)) {
         return x;
     } else {
         throw new RuntimeException("some message goes here...");
     }
 }));
```

It exploits the `O(1)` access time of a `HashMap`, thus waiving the nested loop with complexity `O(n)`.

---

Usually while programming you should take care of both aspects: readablity and performance.

Your plain old java code is pretty readable, though not optimized. In worst case it has complexity `O(n*n)` while using a `Map` you can reduce it to linear `O(n)`.

The difference will make huge sense on processing large lists.

Comment: I used a linear loop solution as a starting point, to also find the stream variant as a not-really-recommended solution, similar to your variant. So +1 for an O(n) solution, though I still recommended the (also O(n)) loop variant.

Comment: Indeed, not trivial, though nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use lambdas for the "coolness" factor. Here's one option:

```
private static void test(List<Foo> a) {
    a.forEach(o1 -> {
        if (a.stream().anyMatch(o2 -> o1.getFooA().equals(o2.getFooA()) && !o1.getFooB().equals(o2.getFooB()))) {
            throw new Exception("some message goes here...");
        }
    });
}
```

Instead of two nested for loops, it's a "forEach" lambda with a nested "anyMatch" that does the same thing. I chose this approach because that makes it more obvious what is going on here.

Comment: `if (a.anyMatch(o1 -> a.stream().anyMatch(o2 -> o1.getFooA().equals(o2.getFooA()) && !o1.getFooB().equals(o2.getFooB())))
    ) { throw new Exception("some message goes here...") };` would better show the purpose

Comment: Mind that you can’t throw `Exception` within a `Consumer`…